# Idioms related to uninteresting topics

Tags: idiom-requests

What idiom(s) rather than "talk of the town" can we use to mean a person who is not talked about these days? It may concern a celebrity who is old and not famous among young people. For example:

> Few young people know who Chuck Norris is. He is definitely *not the
>   talk of the town* anymore.

I'm also interested in what we can call a topic which is not so important anymore. For example:

> Who to vote for *isn't an interesting conversation topic* now that the
>   election is over.

Comment: [*Talk of the town*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talk%20of%20the%20town) works for that, too.

Comment: Perhaps too pejorative is the broadened meaning of **anachronism**: 2. a person or thing that belongs or seems to belong to another time: _she regards the Church as an anachronism_. [[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/anachronism)]

Comment: *So last year!* ; *passe* ; *has been*

Comment: no longer in the spotlight

Comment: "You've had your 15 minutes of fame - you can go now."

Comment: *played out* is how I would refer to the Chuck Norris meme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yesterday's news,**

> [from merriam webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yesterday's%20news)
>
> something or someone that was popular once, but is not popular now
>
> *That actor is yesterday's news.*

and

> [**Yesterday's news** from Oxford online dictionaries (scroll to bottom of link )](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/yesterday)
>
> A person or thing that is no longer of interest.
>
> *‘Now we hear that he has been charged with adultery and having pornographic material in his possession; the espionage accusations are apparently yesterday's news.’*
>
> *BSE is not yesterday's news and anyone who relies on governments to guarantee the safety of what they eat simply hasn't been paying attention…’*

Answer (score 5):

**old hat.**

Used to refer to something considered uninteresting, predictable, tritely familiar, or old-fashioned. (definition reference: Dictionary.com)

Not really used to describe people.

Answer (score 2):

**Washed up** would apply to people.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/washed-up)
>
> no longer successful, skillful, popular, or needed
>
> *washed-up athletes*
>
> *a washed-up actor*

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 : "Few young people know who Chuck Norris is. He is definitely not *flavour of the month* anymore."

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flavour-of-the-month)  **flavour of the month** :

> the most popular person at a particular time: *Andy is certainly flavour of the month with the boss.*

---

Example 2 : "Who to vote for isn't a *pressing issue* now that the election is over."

From [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1CAACAT_enCA736CA736&ei=f-IZW7jNLLu-0PEPj-eqqAw&q=define%20pressing&oq=define%20pressing&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0l4j0i22i30k1l5.1973.5849.0.6207.35.25.0.1.1.0.160.1766.21j3.25.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..18.17.1275.6..33i21k1j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i131i67k1j0i10k1.66.DjZwywwzfZw)  **pressing** (adjective):

> (of a problem, need, or situation) requiring quick or immediate action or attention.

Answer (score 0):

**out of sight, out of mind** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Out+of+Sight%2C+Out+of+Mind)

> you soon forget people or things that are no longer visible or
>   present. proverb

The idioms a 'gone goose' and 'a drop in the bucket' may work for your question too.

Comment: A computer translation program once rendered "out of sight, out of mind" into French as "aveugle, fou", i.e., "blind, insane".

Answer (score 0):

> **"Has-Been"** 
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/has-been   
>  countable noun
>   If you describe someone as a has-been, you are indicating in an unkind way that they were important or respected in the past, but they are not now.

See also the synonyms at http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/has-been  
  Synonyms for has-been
adj no longer in use, in vogue:-
  antiquated
archaic
out-of-date
outmoded
anachronistic
ancient
antediluvian
antique
bygone
dated
dead
dead and gone
dinosaur
discarded
disused
done for
dusty
extinct
fossil
gone
had it
has-been
horse and buggy
kaput
moldy
moth-eaten
old
old-fashioned
old-hat
old-school
out
out-of-fashion